# AutoLayout with iOS below 6.0 - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollview, autolayout

I have a view with a scrollview in it and it requires AutoLayout to be on, otherwise when the screen loads, it is scrolled all the way to the top and and wont scroll down.

The issue is, I have to be able to deploy this project on all devices, but AutoLayout does not work with iOS below 6.0.

Is there anyway, I can make the functionality of AutoLayout work without enabling the AutoLayout option?

Thanks

Comment: iOS below 6.0 can not AutoLayout. Unfortunately, iOS5 use AutoSizing.

Comment: So is there anyway to push the content down and manually lay it out and make it scrollable?

Comment: Are you using xib(IB)?

Comment: Yes, I am using .xibs

Comment: like this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3835237?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Sorry, I get a "page not found" error on that link.

Comment: oh. I edit other page.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually lay out your views in `- (void)layoutSubviews`. This does get called a lot though, so maybe `- (void)viewDidLoad` is a better place to manually layout your views. It depends on your circumstances.

As a side-note, your best bet is probably to drop iOS 5 support as you'll otherwise be supporting three iOS versions soon.

Comment: I ended up manually laying out the view in `viewWillAppear` however, when I try running the project on a iPhone 5.0 simulator, the buttons on the view don't work. It works fine on a iPhone 6.1 simulator. Is there a reason why that is?

Comment: Yea, sure. Here is my `viewWillAppear` http://pastebin.com/AqTsKNca . With this code, it scroll like it should. But in 5.0 simulator, the button on the view does not work. In 6.0 simulator, it does work. :S

Comment: I think it's to do with your content width being 1.

Comment: I just tried setting the width to `self.theScrollView.frame.size.width` and it still did not work. I don't think that is the problem...